# Maximum size of matrix heatmap.2 can handle

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to use heatmap.2 (RStudio) to generate a heatmap with ~40,000 rows and 7 columns.  The desired purpose for the heatmap is not to see individual row, but instead to see a general trend across the ordered dataset.

This works great when I try a much smaller matrix of 35 rows with 7 columns:

```
library(gplots)      #need to bring gplots into library, perform each time
y <- data.matrix(x)  #converting .csv file dataset to a data.matrix
poy <- colorRampPalette(c("purple", "orange", "yellow")) 
heatmap.2(y, col=poy, main = "Test2", trace = "none", margins = c(10,12), Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE)
```

But RStudio seems to get hung up with the full 40,000 x 7 data matrix.  I am turning off the dendrogram functions to save processing power and because I do not want the matrix to be re-clustered.

Is this a processing power issue or is heatmap.2 just not designed for such a large matrix?   Thanks!

Comment: You are running into memory issues, see: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html, depending on if you run 32-bit vs 64-bit and how much RAM your system has.  You can sub-sample for instance by looking at only features with the highest variance, as features that do not change across all samples will not give you pattern information about what is different between samples

Comment: Thanks!  I was afraid of that.  Since I don't need to cluster the data can you recommend any functions other than heatmap.2 that would require less RAM?

Comment: I have never timed the different heatmap functions but I think you are running more into constraints with your system itself and free addressable RAM. You can try running on a capable server, but the common solution for many of us is to subset your data, as I proposed above, plot only the features with the highest variance.

Comment: Thanks!  Will do!